# controlling broadcast from activity

Tags: android

I am doing an android application. In my project I am checking phonestates using broadcast receiver.Using the folowing code I am checking my phonestate.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bun=intent.getExtras();
    if(bun!=null){
        String state=bun.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.w("DEBUG", state);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            String phoneno=bun.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, "phone no. is"+phoneno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want control this application from activity. I mean using an button i have start the broadcast and using an off button i have to close the broadcast run.the second problem is i want run the application when the application is in closed state too. So i think I have call a service from activity and that service make that broadcast receiver to run in the background. And if i want to stop my application's processing open app and click the button to off. Help me friends..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ,

When click on 
Registered your broadcast

```
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiverClass.class, filter);
```

when click off
unregistered your broadcast

```
 unregisterReceiver(new BroadcastReceiverClass());
```

Comment: i put these lines to my activities start buttons onclick method..
   
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    registerReceiver(new bradcastdemo(), filter); 
....bradcastdemo is my broadcast's name....and my broadcast is .. 
<activity 
            android:name=".first" >
            <intent-filter >
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </activity>
  <receiver android:name=".bradcastdemo"
                  >